# T-SQL failed converting varchar to int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, int, varchar

I need to add days to date

```
select Name, Surname, Days, getdate(), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(s,CONVERT(INT, Days) ), getdate()),101 )
from myTAble
```

but i get error

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '20' to data type int.
```

any idea?

Comment: Is that for SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it is for SQL

Comment: Can you create *reproduceable* examplе? Obviously, `select convert(int, '20')` will work as intended without such an error. So problem is somewhere in your data - or maybe error message you've provided is not fully relevant... Have you copy-pasted it exactly? Is there a chance that it is really `2O` (capiltal letter O) instead of `20` in your data?

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a DBMS product. But I assume you _do_ mean "SQL Server"

Comment: in my db 20 is varchar and i need to convert to int

Comment: Why do you store integer data in a varchar column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets mixed up:

```
select Name, Surname, Days, getdate(), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(s,CONVERT(INT, days), getdate()),101) 
from myTAble
```

Answer (score 0):

First your parentesis are incorrect but that's not likely the issue here.
I created a verifiable example:

```
create table MyTable
(
 Name varchar(100)
,Surname varchar(100)
,[Days] varchar(100)
)

GO

insert into MyTable(Name,Surname,[Days])
values ('John', 'Doo', '20')
,('Stack', 'Overflow', char(178) + char(176))
GO
```

And now your query (with correct parentesis)

```
select Name, Surname, Days, getdate(), 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),DATEADD(s,CONVERT(INT, Days ), getdate()),101 )
from myTAble
```

and I managed to reproduce your problem (somewhat)

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '²°' to data type
>   int.

The issue here is you got a `20` is not the correct caracteres, maybe you got a **collation problem**.

In the example above I used a real problem I got a time ago. In the app is shows `20` but in reallity in the database we got non standart caracteres.

In the example below some special caractres can look like numeric ones

```
--° #176 ~ 0   --¹ #185 ~ 1   --² #178 ~ 2   --³ #179 ~ 3    
select char(178) + char(176)
```

You can try to check if the data is numeric

```
select *, isnumeric([Days]) from MyTable
```

In my case we sanitized the data.